# Singular locus of a homogeneous polynomial.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Consider a polynomial $p \in \mathbb C[x_0,\cdots, x_n]$ that is homogeneous under a weighted $\mathbb C^*$ action (we can assume for simplicity that the weights are coprime).  I would ideally like to know

> What is/are necessary and sufficient conditions *on the monomials and coefficients of a polynomial* for its singular locus to be the origin.

By singular locus, I mean the variety defined as the common vanishing locus of $p$ and its derivatives.  I think this probably requires some sort of sufficiently generic choice of terms (both monomials and coefficients), but I don't know how to properly characterize it.

For example, in $\mathbb C[x,y]$, setting $p = x^3$ is homogeneous under any weighted action, but its singular locus is $\mathbb V(x)$.  Similarly, $p = (x-y)^3$ is homogeneous under the diagonal action, but its singular locus is $\mathbb V(x-y)$.  If I take $p = x^2 + y^2$, however, the singular locus is $\mathbb V(x,y)$.

From playing around with various polynomials, I suspect I am looking for something like "$p$ must have 'sufficiently many monomials with generic coefficents'."

**Edit**: Sorry I was not clear; I'm not beginning with a fixed polynomial.  I want to characterize polynomials whose singular locus is the origin.  I suspect there should be a condition that says "if you pick exponents with such and such properties, then a polynomial with those monomials and generic complex coefficients will have singular locus at the origin."

If I pick any non-zero coefficent $a$, the polynomial $p=a x^3$, the singular locus will always be $\mathbb V(x)$, but for arbitrary non-zero coefficents $a,b$, the polynomial $p=a x^2 + b y^2$, the singular locus will always be $\mathbb V(x,y)$.  So a condition might be "if the newton polytope is codimension 1 or less, for generic coefficients the singular locus is the origin".

Comment: I don't think your question is too clear at the moment to get a decent answer, as you answer the question yourself - a neccessary and sufficient condition is given by looking at where the partial derivatives vanish.



Comment: However a "general" hypersurface in projective space will always be non-singular, in that the smooth hypersurfaces form a Zariski open subset of corresponding linear system. 

I would guess the same is true for weighted projective space but unfortunately I am not an expert on it, and perhaps the singularities of weighted projective space might mess things up (but I would guess not as these occur in codimension one). 

Note that a singularity of your variety which is not the origin is exactly a singularity of the corresponding variety in weighted projective space.

Comment: On the weighted hypersurface the quotient singularities can be in any codimension. It is also possible to construct hypersurfaces for which there are nontrivial intersections between the quotient singularities and the singularities that arise when the defining polynomial is not transverse.

Comment: If your weights are pairwise coprime and divide the degree d, then a general degree d hypersurface in this weighted projective space will be smooth. If your weights don't divide the degree, then the hypersurface will always be singular (because it will pass through one of the singular points of the weighted projective space)

Comment: @Daniel: I don't know the definition of general, and googling doesn't reveal anything enlightening.  Would you mind pointing me to a reference?

Comment: "General" means that there is a non-trivial polynomial in the coefficients such that, if this equation doesn't vanish, then the hypersurface is smooth.  (The way it is being used in this discussion, it is a synonym for "generic".)  

Comment: @Emerton: How do I find this polynomial?

Comment: It describes the locus of points where the original polynomial, and all its derivatives, vanish.  The traditional method for computing such things explicitly is called "Elimination theory"; in this particular case (one is trying to find the non-singular locus of a family of hypersurfaces of fixed degree) there are probably well-known ways to work it out, and it is likely much studied --- but I don't know the ways or precise formulas myself.  You might want to look at an introductory book on algebraic geometry, not so much because it will contain the answer, but because ... 

Comment: ... it will give you the background and language you need if you want to pursue these kinds of questions.  (If you look at some of the MO threads on algebraic geometry texts, you will get a sense of what books are out there and which ones might help you.  You don't want to try a huge tome like Hartshorne unless there is a pressing need to do so, but there are lots of other texts that are much easier to skim, and which you might find interesting in light of the questions you are asking.  Probably plugging in "Elimination theory" into google will also bring up interesting material.)

Comment: One more remark: if you ask a question such as "how do I explicitly compute/describe the non-singular locus for a family of hypersurfaces in weighted projective space", it might attract the attention of a wandering expert.  (And my view --- but I speak only for myself here --- is that it would be sufficiently different from this question that it shouldn't be closed as a duplicate.)  Finally, I want to draw attention again to mdeland's comment, to the effect that in the weighted context, for some degrees it can happen that *every* hypersurface is singular; this discussion of "general" ...

Comment: ... hypersurfaces being non-sigular applies only in those cases when the weights divide the degree.

Comment: This question has been re-posed and answered: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40672/constructing-affine-hypersurfaces-with-one-singularity